# Page content loaded with ajax - events firing multiple times

Tags: java, jquery, html

So I am loading my page using ajax, and everything is working fine using below

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    menuLoad('auction');
});

function menuLoad(page){    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/content/'+page+'/'+page+'.php',
        async : false,
        success: function (response) {
            location.hash = page;
            $("#contentLoad").html(response);
        }
    })
};
```

however if i try loading the same page multiple times, all buttons click events will fire multiple times.. I understand that every time I am loading the content, I am re-assigning a new event to the button while it already have one which cause each event to fire when a user click on it.. but how to fix this?

inside page content, the button will be something like below

```
<input type="button" value='New Sold' id='soldaddbtn' >

$( document ).on("click", "#soldaddbtn", function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/content/sold/loadSoldAdd.php",
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(response){
            bootbox.dialog({message: response});
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

define a global variable and check for its existence.

```
if(!soldaddbtnClickEventisAdded) { // check if the variable is defined file is already loaded
    $( document ).on("click", "#soldaddbtn", function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/content/sold/loadSoldAdd.php",
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(response){
                bootbox.dialog({message: response});
            }
        });
    });
}

var soldaddbtnClickEventisAdded = true; // add a global variable
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand your problem completely but try using following code:

As on() will bind the click event, so there might be the case that event is bounded multiple times. So unbind the click event then bind it again.

```
$("#soldaddbtn").off("click").on("click", function(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

its `javascript` not `java`, you need event to fire once, the replace

```
$( document ).on("click", "#soldaddbtn", function(){
```

with

```
$("#soldaddbtn").on("click", function(){
```

Comment: that worked for some elements but not the one dynamically created.. any help is appreciated man!

Comment: do you have `$( document ).on("click", "#soldaddbtn",...` on every page content?